# Como calcular números em um determinado intervalo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for

Como eu poderia calcular a soma dos números em um intervalo de 1 a 500 no qual os números somados desse intervalo devem ser **ímpares** e **múltiplo de três**?

Eu só consegui fazer o intervalo até agora:

```
for c in range(3, 500, 3):
    if c % 2 != 0:
```

Comment: o problema aí "agora" não é somar é descobrir quais são primos, tente desenvolver um algorítimo que descubra se é um número ímpar, ai se vai montando seu código...

Comment: Acho que consegui, e agora?

Comment: Que tal `print(20667)`?

Comment: @MagicHat Este problema não tem nada a ver com números primos.

Comment: Você pode somar os números de 6 em 6. Veja bem: 3, 9, 15, 21, 27...

Comment: @VictorStafusa eu ia falar isso

Comment: Desculpe, mas ainda não entendo como posso escrever a soma em forma de código.

Comment: Acho que já tá bom de negativos, afinal o AP editou e tornou um aquestão válida. Alias 1 negativo creio ser suficiente para indicar que algo está errado, esse post não justifica negativos em massa.

Comment: `soma = soma + c`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Essa pergunta parece ser bastante um exercício comum em iniciação à programação e responderei como tal. Já fui monitor da disciplina de algoritmos na universidade e sempre notei que os alunos tem uma saciedade em resolver o problema sem ao menos analisá-lo.

**Solução 1**

A primeira solução que eu vejo e, com certeza, a mais simples, é analisar o problema matematicamente, já que é... um problema de matemática. A soma de todos os números, dentro do intervalo 1 a 500, ímpares e múltiplos de 3 são:

```
 S = 3 + 9 + 15 + 21 + ... + 495
```

É fácil perceber que um número é sempre o anterior somado em 6 (como cantado nos [comentários pelo Victor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/248785/como-calcular-n%C3%BAmeros-em-um-determinado-intervalo/248797#comment510159_248785)). Isso claramente forma a soma de uma [progressão aritmética](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiK5ej-jYjXAhXMnJAKHcghDfkQFggvMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpt.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FProgress%25C3%25A3o_aritm%25C3%25A9tica&usg=AOvVaw2KzpV0V-4KMnXpy4f4lE-Q), do qual pode ser formulada:

```
S = (N/2)*(a_1 + a_N)
  = (N/2)*(3 + 495)
```

Sendo `N` o número de elementos somados. Para calcular, bastaríamos analisar a expressão do termo geral da progressão:

```
a_n = a_1 + (n-1)*r
```

Sabendo que 495 é o último elemento, `a_N`, 3 é o primeiro, `a_1`, e a razão é 6, `r`, temos:

```
N = (a_N - a_1)/6 + 1
  = (495 - 3)/6 + 1
  = 83
```

Assim sabemos que há 83 elementos sendo somados. Voltando a fórmula da soma:

```
S = (N/2)*(a_1 + a_N)
  = (83/2)*(3 + 495)
  = 20667
```

Portanto, a primeira solução, seria fazer:

```
a_1 = 3
a_N = 495
r = 6

N = (a_N - a_1)/r + 1
S = N/2 * (a_1 + a_N)

print(S)
```

<sub>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/7i5jTm) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/NGyd/0)</sub>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O tempo de cálculo se mantém constante, independente da grandeza de `N`.

**Solução 2**

Fazer um laço de repetição entre todos os valores, verificar quais são ímpares e múltiplos de 3 e, quando somar, somar em uma variável:

```
S = 0
for x in range(1, 500):
    if x % 2 != 0 and x % 3 == 0:
        S = S + x
print(S)
```

<sub>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/98HP06) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/NGzN/0)</sub>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O tempo de cálculo cresce linearmente conforme o valor de `N`.

**Solução 3**

Podemos simplificar a solução acima utilizando compreensão de listas do Python, junto com a função nativa `sum`:

```
S = sum(x for x in range(1, 500) if x % 2 != 0 and x % 3 == 0)
print(S)
```

<sub>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/TbV8qP) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/NGzb/0)</sub>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O tempo de cálculo cresce linearmente conforme o valor de `N`.

**Solução 4**

Podemos simplificar ainda mais a solução acima utilizando o intervalo de 6 em 6 como aplicado na solução matemática e, sabendo que o primeiro valor a ser considerado será o 3, temos:

```
S = sum(range(3, 500, 6))
print(S)
```

<sub>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/H6ZJfz) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/NGzp/0)</sub>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O tempo de cálculo cresce linearmente conforme o valor de `N`.

**Por quê a análise matemática seria importante se a com laço de repetição é mais fácil?**

Desempenho. Com um [pequeno teste de tempo de execução](https://ideone.com/EkvoEV) com o módulo `timeit`, fiz o tempo necessário para executar 1000 vezes cada solução, imprimindo o tempo gasto:

```
Tempo gasto para calcular 1000x cada solução:
Solução 1: 0.0003348870013724081
Solução 2: 0.06511368200153811
Solução 3: 0.06661822800015216
Solução 4: 0.0016278160001093056
```

Se normalizarmos em relação à solução 1, que é a mais rápida, temos:

```
Solução 1: 1.0
Solução 2: 194.43478467272314
Solução 3: 198.927482186954
Solução 4: 4.8607918295971935
```

Ou seja, as soluções 2 e 3 levam cerca de 200x o tempo de execução da solução 1, quanto a solução 4 leva cerca de 5x, pelo fato da solução 1 possuir complexidade O(1), isto é, sempre fará o mesmo número de operações, independente do intervalo, e as outras três soluções são O(n), tendo o número de operações aumentado linearmente com o intervalo considerado.

Answer (score 2):

**Resposta errada, consertei abaixo no edite**

Utilizando as dicas no comentário, podes fazer algo assim:

```
for c in range(3, 500, 3):
    soma = c + c
print(soma)
```

Veja no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/uV8kBw)

**Edit**

Bem observado pelo @Anderson Carlos Woss, a resposta acima está errada e consertada da seguinte forma

```
cur = [] #declara a lista para receber os ímpares multiplos de 3
for c in range(0, 500,3): # o loop para percorrer a lista gerada pelo range
    if (c % 2 != 0) and (c % 3 == 0): #checa se o valor corrente é primo e multiplo de 3
        cur.append(c) #adiciona a lista
print(sum(cur)) #printa a soma dos itens da lista
```

Veja no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/p8teVJ)

Comment: Acho que tem algo errado na resposta. Tem certeza que é `c+c`, pois assim `soma` seria o dobro do último múltiplo de 3 no intervalo, 498. Mesmo que fosse `soma += c`, ainda estaria considerando os números pares. A dica do Victor para ir de 6 em 6 parece resolver o problema.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss consertei, veja se agrada.